# Length variável - SAS

Tags: concatenação-de-string, sas

Estou fazendo um if no SAS para declarar o valor que uma variável irá receber dependendo a condição, porém quando digo que a variável irá receber um string de tamanho até 3 ele retorna corretamente, mas ao indicar que receberá uma string de tamanho 4 ou maior, ele retorna apenas os 3 primeiros caracteres!

Código Exemplo:

```
    IF   RECEITA 1000000 AND  RECEITA_ LE 10000000 THEN
    P = '>1'||'M';

ELSE IF  RECEITA 10000000 THEN
    P = '>10'||'M';
```

No primeiro caso ele retorna corretamente, ou seja, >1M. Já no segundo caso ele retorna >10, faltando o caractere 'M'.

Já tentei a funções como cat e substr, e até mesmo apenas declarar, por exemplo, P = ">10M", mas  acontece o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Voce deve informar que o P tem 4 caracteres Strings, pois o SAS assume o tipo na sua primeira vez que vê a variavel, como o primeiro P é de 3 caracteres, ele assume isso.

Faça o teste abaixo que irá funcionar;

```
data t1;
     format P $4.;
     set TABELA;
     IF   RECEITA 1000000 AND  RECEITA_ LE 10000000 THEN
        P = '>1'||'M';
     ELSE IF  RECEITA 10000000 THEN
        P = '>10'||'M';
run;
```